# Сравнение String

Tags: java, строки, сравнение, equals

Как сделать сравнение строк.

```
В int это - if((a > b)&&(a > c)), 
а как это сделать в String? - if((a.equals(b))&&(a.equals(c))). 
Как поставить знак ">"?
```

Пример: ввести три слова, и, в каком слове больше букв - то на экране: "Слово a больше всех"

Comment: Сравнивайте не сами строки,  но их длину. Так вы будете сравнивать числа, с чем проблем не будет)

Answer (score 2):

Используй .length() для строк что-бы узнать их длину.

```
    String a = "аaaa";
    String b = "bb";

    if(a.length()>b.length()) {
        System.out.println("Строка- " +a+" Больше");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Строка- " +b+" Больше");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Например, вот так:

```
Math.max(a.lenght(), b.lenght()) == a.lenght() 
     && Math.max(a.lenght(), c.lenght()) == a.lenght());
```